# Error occured when I import a gradle module using Intellij Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I want to use a gradle project as a library of my project.However,when I import it,the Intellij show the message like: "Gradle version 1.8 is required. Current version is 1.9. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0\jre\jre\bin\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.8-all.zip."

In fact ,the gradle version of my system is gradle1.8,and I also change the version of gradle-wrapper.properties in the project.In the folder of Intellij,there is only one "~\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle\wrapper\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties".But though I change all of them,the Error also occur.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'm lost and desperate! Gradle is confused about what it wants; version 1.8 or 1.9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088879/im-lost-and-desperate-gradle-is-confused-about-what-it-wants-version-1-8-or-1)

Comment: @kukido Thank you!In that question it's good to update the version of gradle but in fact I do not want to use gradle 1.9 because I don't know much about the newer version.